# Is there a better Python bundle for textmate than the one in the bundle repository?

Tags: python, textmate, textmatebundles

At this time Textmate's official Python bundle is really bare bones, especially in comparison to the Ruby bundle. Does anyone know of a Python bundle that is more complete?

EDIT:

I am fully aware that there are editors and environments that are better suited to Python development, but I am really just interested to see if there is a third party Textmate bundle available.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I took a look and noticed that there has been a lot of work on Python-related bundles recently. Also, it seems I missed the memo on the best [new way](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304014953/http://al3x.net/2008/12/03/how-i-use-textmate.html) to get bundles:

[Install GetBundles](https://web.archive.org/web/20170527031757/http://solutions.treypiepmeier.com:80/2009/02/25/installing-getbundles-on-a-fresh-copy-of-textmate)

Comment: Looks like that 2nd link is 404

Answer (score -18):

I use [Komodo Edit](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/) and [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/) for MacOS development.

1. They handle Python whitespace perfectly.
2. It's easy to roll my own snippets and components in either tool.
3. They are really good editors for Python.

But I don't want to discuss these things.

Comment: Yes, I know about these editors already, and I use vim cross-platform with great success, so this really doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @guns: Here's the point.  Consider changing to another IDE.  It might be better than textmate.

Comment: @S.Lott I have already mentioned that I believe that there are better editors for Python. What are you trying to prove? I was gathering information for more than just myself.

Comment: @guns: I was trying to provide information for anyone else considering Mac OS IDE's.  Also, I don't understand your question.  Why list things you don't want to discuss?

Comment: @S.Lott I listed them so that I could avoid answers like yours actually. I see that was a mistake. And also, the question is specifically tagged 'Textmate'. If I wanted advice about Mac IDEs in general, don't you think I would have tagged it as such?

Comment: @guns: Sorry, but, when one IDE doesn't work very well, do you suspect it might be time to change?  Or are you going to stick with that IDE in spite of it not meeting your requirements?  Here's my point:  I think you can solve your problem by ditching textmate.  You don't have to agree.

Comment: @S.Lott You're reading too much into my question. My problem is not that I cannot find a proper Python editor, nor is it that I use Textmate religiously (I don't). I was asking a very specific question and wanted a specific answer, which is what I thought StackOverflow was all about.

Comment: @S.Lott I'm not sure why you have to be so snarky and insulting. Do you also go around to questions about ruby and answer "use python"?

Comment: @guns: I tried to help by offering two solutions -- (1) use a different IDE if textmate doesn't meet your requirements, and (2) some links to other folks using Textmate for Python.  I'm not sure what's snarky about two complementary solutions.

Comment: @S.Lott Your answer was a mockery of my question, and that link was an insulting page leading to the google results of "textmate python".

Comment: @guns: It appears that both contain solutions to your problem.  I'm not sure how a Google search result can be insulting, but you're free to interpret it any way you want to interpret it.